# VBA to find and transfer data

Tags: vba, excel

I have a daily process where I receive 26 excel spreadsheets per day.  We manually open these spreadsheets print them and then copy 4 relevant values and paste them into a different workbook that consolidates the entire month's 26 sheets.  I have written the following code thus far which opens the 26 books and prints them.  I think adding the second set of code I have before the loop will allow it to find the 4 values and paste the values in the right spot (once the code is completed).  I know how to find the 4 cells, I am just not certain of how to get the destination.  I have a text box that I enter the row I want to put the data into for the day, but how do I find the column and then the intersection of these two?

```
Sub LockBox2()

    'Opens all of the xls and xlsx files in the file path


    Dim DestRow As Variant
    DestRow = InputBox("Enter Desired Destination Row")

        Dim MyFolder As String
        Dim MyFile As String
        MyFolder = "C:\Users\ahendr1\Desktop\WIP Files\Lock Box Sheets Proj"

        MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.xls")
        Do While MyFile <> ""
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyFolder & "\" & MyFile


                ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
                '''''Prints the desired "Sheet 1" ''''
                ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

                    Dim sh As Worksheet
                        For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
                        If (sh.Name = "Sheet1") Then
                           sh.PrintOut
                        End If
                    Next sh
                ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
                ''''''End of Print''''''''''''''''''''
                ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

        MyFile = Dir

        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        ''''Insert Code To Copy 1st of 4 cell values in Lockbox sheet and paste into the destination sheet at ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        '''' the intersection of the row entered into the dialogbox and the column header of the destination sheet''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

        'Selects the desired cell to copy
            Dim GeneralRtnItems As Range
            Dim OffsetCell As Range
            With Sheets("Sheet1")
                Set GeneralRtnItems = .Cells.Find(what:="General Rtn Items")
                Set OffsetCell = GeneralRtnItems.Offset(0, -1)
            End With

            OffsetCell.Copy _
                Destination:=Workbooks("1-AugLockBox.xlsx").Worksheets("Summary").Range("F20")
        '''''''Code above sends the desired data to F20, but I need this to be dynamic and be Roww 22(from dialog box)
        '''''''and column where "17 Reg 04" is the column header
        '''''''Alternatively it could use the source workbook's name as the header in the destination workbook and use it to
        '''''''find the intersection and set the value in the cell


        '''''Enter Code to Close the Source File'''''''''''''''''''''
        '''''Will this work with the method that I am using to open the files on my desktop?
        '''''or will the loop never stop if I close the file (because there would always be an unopened file in the folder
        '''''could I close the file and move it to a completed folder to get around this potential issue?
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

        Loop


'''''''''''''''''''''''''
'''''''''''''''''''''''''
'''''''END STAGE 1'''''''
'''''''''''''''''''''''''
'''''''''''''''''''''''''

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To copy the cell to the Summary sheet, where row is `DestRow` and the column which has "17 Reg 04" in row 1, use:

```
With Workbooks("1-AugLockBox.xlsx").Worksheets("Summary")
    OffsetCell.Copy _
        Destination:=.Cells(DestRow, .Rows(1).Find(what:="17 Reg 04").Column)
End With
```

---

To copy the cell to the Summary sheet, where row is `DestRow` and the column which has the current filename (ignoring the extension) in row 1, first move the line saying

```
MyFile = Dir
```

to somewhere below the section copying cells (it's usually best to put that just before the end of the loop), and then use:

```
With Workbooks("1-AugLockBox.xlsx").Worksheets("Summary")
    OffsetCell.Copy _
        Destination:=.Cells(DestRow, .Rows(1).Find(what:=Left(MyFile, InstrRev(MyFile, ".") - 1)).Column)
End With
```

Comment: The second solution is the one I really needed as it is dynamic.  Thanks for you help.